# How to align horizontal scrollview images to the bottom?

Tags: react-native

[How to get the second image align to the bottom line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV8yU.png)

I am trying to align the second image to the bottom without having it stretch:

```
container: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 0.225 * screenHeight, //190
        width: 0.461 * screenWidth, //180
        marginRight: 0,
        marginBottom:100,
        
    },
    imageContainer: {

    },
    image: {
        height: '100%',
        width:'92%',
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
```

How can I have the second image aligned to the bottom without changing dimensions?  Keep in mind HEIGHT should not be the same.

I tried `flex: 1`, `column` and `justifyContents` but none worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the image size dynamically to Image component, and then set justifyContent to flex-end using a wrapper.

https://snack.expo.dev/@gersonmontenegro/align-bottom

Comment: It is only working on the snack, I have tried it with the version I have, it is not working at all. it is not recognizing resizing I guess, this is what im receiving by just copying the exact way you have added them on expo. 

https://ibb.co/0f44rvg